# C++ adaptor with different interfaces, where interfaces may have different type/number of input parameters

Tags: c++, adapter

It is well know how to build the adapter when the adaptee's methods look same except for the name.

For example,

http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter/cpp/2

where none of "doThis", "doThat", and "doOther" has inputs. However, what if different methods have different number of input parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Then your adapters would need to pass some arguments...

Answer (score 1):

The example given in linked document describes a use of the adapter pattern in a situation where the change is purely syntactic. The situation implied by your question contains a semantic change, ie the adaptee method does not provide the exact same service than what the adapter interface "promises" to deliver formally. This means that the adaptee's must be somehow wrapped with more than a simple name change: some work must be done around it to build the missing parameters or transform the existing parameters into those required by the adaptee.

If each new adaptee has different requirements, then each adapter must contain the ad-hoc adapting code. There's not much one can do to factor out a common pattern out of this situation. The only easy case is the trivial one, when all the needed parameters are independent of the passed ones, and can be computed once for all before constructing the adapter, hence allowing an adapter as a simple `std::bind` equivalent.